# I want to run my cakephp code

Tags: cakephp-2.5

Im started learning cakephp, and I did something but how I can run it? Where I can see what im made and see does it works ?

I tried typing just /app/View/Posts/index.ctp in to URL bar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you had to read this : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html.

Your url depends on a lot of parameters , Router , Controller.

Default usage :

When you url is : site.com/presentation/user/a/b/c

it calls the "presentationController" , and the "user" method of this controller. and add parameters a, b  , c.

Your controller will look

```
PresentationController extends AppController{

    //$param 1 = a  , $param2 = b , $param c=3 (in the example above)
    //it will call the view (by default again) View/presentation/user.ctp
    public function user($param1,$param2,$param3){
        //do what you want with params or call models or others...
    }
}
```